# как конвертировать esd в iso на linux

Tags: linux, windows-10

у меня стоит kali linux так как из-за санкций нету возможности скачать образ винды я скачал esd теперь не знаю как в iso конвертировать

Comment: Я правильно понимаю: ты качнул Kali, потому что `3117тный ][@k3R`, но из-за бана по geoip - у тебя нет обходных путей, чтобы качнуть винду с оф сайта майков? Я ничего не перепутал, не упустил, неправильно понял?

Answer (score 0):

1. Установите `wimlib`: например `sudo apt-get install wimtools`.
2. Сконвертируйте ESD в WIM:`esd2wim path/to/source.esd path/to/destination.wim`.
3. Создайте ISO из WIM:`wimlib-imagex capture path/to/destination.wim "Название вашего образа" path/to/output.iso`.